# ehcache + Hibernate + hibernate Restrictions.like query

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

I have a list of data in a lookup table I'm trying to cache using ehcache. I notice the cache is being populated with the data properly, however when ever I use .add( Restrictions.like("name", "Fritz%")) in my criteria query, it doesn't appear to hit the 2nd level cache. Is there a way to configure ehcache to look in the cache using a string value rather than just an Id?

query example

```
List cats = sess.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .add( Restrictions.like("name", "Fritz%") )
    .setCacheable(true)
    .list();
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <!-- Enable Second-Level Cache and Query Cache Settings --> 
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>         
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>         
    <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</property>
```

Entity

```
@Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Cat implements Serializable {

private String name;
```

logs

```
stat.Statistics HQL: null, time: 1ms, rows: 0
cache.StandardQueryCache caching query results in region: org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache; timestamp=5516849224093696
cache.UpdateTimestampsCache Pre-invalidating space [vehicle_trim_level]
cache.UpdateTimestampsCache Pre-invalidating space [vehicle_model]
cache.UpdateTimestampsCache Invalidating space [vehicle_model], timestamp: 5516849224110081
cache.UpdateTimestampsCache Invalidating space [vehicle_trim_level], timestamp: 5516849224110081
cache.UpdateTimestampsCache Pre-invalidating space [vehicle]
stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl Logging statistics....
stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl start time: 1346820087066
stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl sessions opened: 57
stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl sessions closed: 56
stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl transactions: 1211
stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl successful transactions: 1153
stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl optimistic lock failures: 0
stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl flushes: 1153
stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl connections obtained: 1212
stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl statements prepared: 2444
stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl statements closed: 2444
stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl second level cache puts: 540
stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl second level cache hits: 0
stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl second level cache misses: 0
stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl entities loaded: 125
stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl entities updated: 710
stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl entities inserted: 475
stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl entities deleted: 0
stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl entities fetched (minimize this): 0
stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl collections loaded: 8
stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl collections updated: 0
stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl collections removed: 0
stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl collections recreated: 0
stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl collections fetched (minimize this): 8
stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl queries executed to database: 719
stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl query cache puts: 680
stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl query cache hits: 494
stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl query cache misses: 680
stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl max query time: 10ms
cache.UpdateTimestampsCache Pre-invalidating space [vehicle_trim_level]
cache.UpdateTimestampsCache Invalidating space [vehicle], timestamp: 5516849228881920
cache.UpdateTimestampsCache Invalidating space [vehicle_trim_level], timestamp: 5516849228881920
```

Comment: Have you enabled the query cache?

Comment: @JB Nizet I sure have, I just posted my other settings.

Comment: And have you executed the query twice? Because it has to execute once against the database to be able to cache the results.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, I'm hitting the query thousands of times in a batch job. I've attached some longs too. I tried narrowing my log down to a single query, but the batch is actually performing 4 lookups. Hopefully it's enough to help understand where my issue may be. Thanks JB

Comment: I'm noticing the result set timestamps are different. Is the cache being consistently updated causing the time stamps to fall out of sync. cache.UpdateTimestampsCache [vehicle_make] last update timestamp: 5516884056555520, result set timestamp: 5516884060401664